# Why is my /usr/local/bin only accessible by root user? Which rights to fix it?

Tags: macos

I recently wanted to use pod to update the path of a framework.

Cocoapods is installed and can be find here :

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

But surprise! It is set to root only access :

```
ls -l /usr/local
drwx------   504    wheel  bin/
drwxr-xr-x@  john   staff  include/
drwxr-xr-x@  john   staff  lib/
drwxr-xr-x   root   wheel  share/
```

---

So I can't use pod because in any case :

- pod install realm

  > heeeyy dude, you can't access pod cause you are not root .!.
- sudo pod install realm

  > heeeyy dude, you can’t use pod as a root! .!.

I feel that this folder shouldn't be set as 'root only' because:

- It is in the env PATH of the usr
- gem install pod in it?
- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html basically says :

  > '/usr/local' is widely regarded as a good place in which to keep self-compiled or third-party programs.

I know Linux isn't a BSD but still, it doesn't look that much different no o.O

---

Finally here are my questions:

- **I searched and there is no user with the uid 504, is this suspicious?**

(I checked it with ""dscacheutil -q user | grep 504"")

- **What are suposed to be the rights and owner on the folder?**
- **Is there someone who had the same problem?**
- **Any idea about why this happened?**

Comment: Did you ever use MacPorts or something similar? The reason I ask is on my system, uid 504 is polkituser which is apparently sometimes created by MacPorts, so it's possible it was a user that has since been removed.

Comment: I think I used it once yes, so it might be this I guess. Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setup for /usr/local is shown here

```
~ $ ls -ld /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  102  5 Aug 20:01 /usr/local
```

this means that files and directorries under /usr/local can only be created by the root user e.g. my /usr/local has

```
~ $ ls -l /usr/local
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel  408 11 Sep 12:11 bin
```

So your share directory looks normal but the others have odd changes

include and lib look like you changed the permissions of /usr/local so you could write to it and then created these two directories (The most common setup like that is installing Homebrew) (we need to see what `ls -ld /usr/local` shows.

As for bin there must have been several things. First a new user must have been added at some time, normal users (created through the System Preferences GUI start at 501) e.g. I am the second user and so my id is 502 and then the directory was created or chowned to that user- or the directory was created elsewhere and then moved as root to where it is.
Separately the permissions of the directory have been changed by `chmod 700`

So the correct setting is as per /usr/local/share unless you are using Homebrew in its default install and then they should be like /usr/local/include

Comment: I found an old wireshark file in /usr/local/bin that was owned by the uid 504! (since removed)
I have only RubyGems and Macports installed, no Homebrew
`ls -ld /usr/local` shows `drwxr-xr-x root  wheel  /usr/local/`
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The /usr folder is protected by System Integrity Protection (SIP) and owned by root, as are all of its contents, with the sole exception of /usr/local (and its subdirectories).

The root user is uid 0, not 504. The 500-series should be user- or app-created accounts. /usr/local/bin on my system is owned by my username "tubedogg" in group "admin", and has `drwxrwxr-x` as the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll update these rights \o/
Yes I know that the root ID is 0 but the rights on the folder are  drwx------ so only root could access it, that's what I meant.
I didn't know for the 500+ IDs, thank you

Answer (score -1):

The `/usr/local/` itself is owned by `root wheel` for me. But all folders that you might use as pods user `bin include etc lib opt share var` are owned by my user and admin group.

To change the ownership of a folder and files in it run:

`sudo chown -R john:staff /usr/local/bin
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Can't upvote the answers tho o/ (not enough reputation)